# Zip uploader php

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload, zip

I would like to create a zip uploader php code. I'm using 000webhost because it is free. There I have a file strorage there is my html and php files. How can I upload there the zip file with php or html or javascript?

Comment: Ask 000webhost or have a look at their documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just upload a zip, you can use sftp.

[More details can be found about sftp here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)

However if you are looking for syncing the files between your development machine and the live URL (on 000webhost), you can utilize rsync also.

[You can read more about rsync here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps)

Also if you have command line access to 000webhost, the best would be using Git and pulling the relevant branch on the 000webhost server.